# Prevent Ctrl+Z deleting last line in SSMS after Script As->Alter View

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm hoping there's just some way to disable this in SQL Server Management Studio (v17.9.1).  When I `Script As->Alter` a view or stored procedure to a new query window, I can hit `Ctrl+Z` and it deletes the last line of text!  I realize as I'm trying to explain this exactly what's happening: Sql is opening a new window and "pasting" the query line by line.  Therefore when you undo you're removing the last line and so on.

This becomes a problem when you say, alter a view, make changes and execute, then decide to undo them all so you just hold `Ctrl+Z` then realize you've erased half your script instead of just going back to the starting point.

Does anyone know how to disable this or an elegant way of preventing it from happening?

Comment: `Script As -> Alter -> New query editor`, `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+X`, `Ctrl+N`, `Ctrl+V`...

Comment: `Script As -> Alter -> To clipboard`, `Ctrl+N`, `Ctrl+V`...

Comment: Happened to me today: didn't realise I'd silently removed the WHERE clause from an UPDATE statement, ran the ALTER, then updated every row in the table - ouch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started out as a comment, but it's getting too long, so...

I don't think you can disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, but just like Newton's third law of motion - for every undo there's an equal and opposite redo - so if you've held <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> pressed for too long, you can always restore the lines that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> deleted simply by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

Other options are suggested by GSerg in his comments - you can always keep a copy of the original code in a different query window, or even a simple text editor.

One more option is to first save the content of the new query to a file, so you can always reload it's original state if you've messed things up too much.

Comment: I guess I'll accept that there isn't really a *disabling* it.  Appreciate the ideas, I'll just have to change that habit.